# Write to file, but overwrite it if it exists with DevIL and REPA

Tags: haskell, devil, repa

I am using the DevIL library to read and write images. The problems is that I want to **overwrite** the file if it already exists.

Here is my code:

```
(RGB v) <- runIL $ readImage "/foo/foo.png"
let rotated = (computeS $ batman v) :: Array F DIM3 Word8
runIL $ writeImage ("/foo/foo.png") (RGB rotated)
```

**How can I achieve that? Can I do this or do I have to think of another way? It is something of the OS?**

I am using that file as a temporary image until the user decides to save it (after some changes, like rotating it, expanding it, etc).

Comment: Have you tried saving an image to a file that already exists? What happened in that case?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you can check whether the file exists with [`doesFileExist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:doesFileExist) and delete it before you save the new file.

Comment: When i save an image to a file that already exist, the program exits with a message ("Unable to save file"). I check the DevIL source code and i didnt get any answer. I will try what you said. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write up an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library won't let you replace an existing file directly, you can check whether the file exists with [`doesFileExist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.1/docs/System-Directory.html#v:doesFileExist) and delete it before you save the new file.

```
replace = do    
  let fn = "path/to/image/file/..."
  exists <- doesFileExist fn
  when exists $ removeFile fn
  runIL $ writeImage fn (RGB rotated)
```

Comment: I just got this error, "Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘IO Bool’". What can it be?

Comment: My bad. It's an IO action rather than a pure functionm, so you have to extract the value or use something like `whenM`. I'll edit.